# Tail Recursion in java

Tags: java

Is this a good example to show tail recursion?

```
public printName(){
    System.out.println("Smith");
    printName();
}
```

I'm not intending to do this in real life, but i put this as an example for my exam. Is this one correct?

Comment: It is an even better example to show stack overflow :)

Comment: Yes, except that this will result in infinite recursion (and crash the program when stack space runs out).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sometimes i come back to view your comment. it never fails to cheer me up.

Answer (score 20):

No, for two reasons:

- tail recursion is only valuable when compiler supports it (*tail call optimization*). In Java it will still end with `StackOverflowError`
- it would be nice to show some stop condition. Your code is equivalent to loop running forever.

Consider almost identical code in Scala, the only difference is that Scala compiler *will* perform tail call optimization and the loop runs forever:

```
def printName() {
  println("Smith"); 
  printName()
}
```

Comment: I don't know: tail recursion is just tail recursion. The compiler can optimize it, but it is besides the point. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @nhahtdh: the OP is not asking whether this is tail recursion or not (no doubt in that). He is asking whether this is a **good example** of tail recursion. IMHO it's not.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and my own CS memories it does not matter whether or not the language handles tail recursion specially - the example is tail-recursive.

Comment: @A.H.: the fact that the last statement is a recursive call doesn't make tail recursion so important (for the same reason we are not teaching about *head recursion*) - it's the fact that it can be optimized to simple loop. Showing an example of tail recursion on a language that does not support it is misleading - it won't buy you anything in Java. So it's *not* a good example without extra remark ("*note that in Java...*") - so why not show it in pseudo-code or in a language where tail-recursion is actually meaningful? Otherwise you'll see Java developers *thinking* they gained something

Answer (score 15):

A better example of tail recursion would be something like this:

```
public printName(int level){
    if( level <= 0 )
         return;
    System.out.prntln("Smith");
    printName(--level);
}
```

This examples includes the important part where the recursion is terminated.

Besides of this: As other answers already noted: Since Java does not optimize tail-recursion, there is no point in using it in this language. So you basically end up to optimize your algorithm yourself - by making it iterative. That's the point of tail-recursion: It can be proved, that any tail-recursive algorithm can be transformed into an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is an example of tail recursion, as you recurse in the tail of the program :) I do however not think that the JVM will optimize this, which is probably what you want.