# Pure tail recursive implementation of Math.add() still throws stackoverflow

Tags: java, recursion

I'm making a class that implements the java Math class and I'm overwriting the add method with a recursive one. I thought my method was pure tail recursive and wouldn't throw a stackoverflow, but I can't add 10000 and 10000 without throwing that.

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return add(increase(a), decrease(b));
}
```

And the increase and decrease methods simply take in the number, add/subtract 1, and return the result. I don't think this should be creating any stack, as the method does not have to wait on any calculations from successive calls to finish. But I'm apparently wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the JVM prevent tail call optimizations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations)

Comment: While that post is old, it is still accurate (and [it never made it into Java 8, either](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/mlvm-dev/2010-October/002016.html)). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616483/why-does-the-jvm-still-not-support-tail-call-optimization

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler does not support tail call optimization. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592796/tail-recursion-in-java) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826786/does-java-support-and-optimize-away-tail-recursive-calls) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I saw several things online saying that Java does not support tail call optimization, but my professor insists that we should not be getting any stack overflows with any valid positive integer calculations. He's even mentioned in class that Java does not support optimization, so I don't know if we're supposed to somehow change the entire functioning of Java or what haha

Comment: Did he require you to use tail recursion and to use Java?

Comment: Java and recursion are required. Tail recursion was strongly suggested.